# JAXB using @XmlJavaTypeAdapter to marshal a subset of a Collection

Tags: java, jaxb, xmladapter

I've got an entity which contains a collection of a different type of entities. What I want to do is have JAXB marshal only a select subset of the collection, based on some criteria.

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
public class A{

    // other fields
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "x", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<B> bees;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BFormatter.class)
    public Collection<B> getBees() {
        return bees;
    }

    public void setBees(Collection<B> bees) {
        this.bees= bees;
    }
}


@XmlRootElement
@Entity
public class B{
    // fields
}

public class BFormatter extends XmlAdapter<Collection<B>, Collection<B>>{

    @Override
    public Collection<B> unmarshal(Collection<B> v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<B> marshal(Collection<B> v) throws Exception {
        Collection<B> subset;
        // making subset
        return subset;
    }

}
```

This results in errors saying "java.util.Collection is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces" and that "java.util.Collection does not have a no-arg default constructor."

What am I doing wrong, and is this even the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing is that you can't adapt a Collection (an interface) to something JAXB can handle, since it doesn't marshal an ArrayList or some other *collection class*. It is designed to marshal (bean) classes *containing* fields that are Lists or similar, which is meant to "disappear", remaining as the mere *repetition* of its elements. In other words, there's no XML element representing the ArrayList (or whatever) itself.

Therefore, the adapter has to modify the *containing* element. (See below for alternatives.) The following classes are working; just assemble a Root element and modify the AFormatter according to your design. (The comments refer to the example at 
https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_6_2_9-Type-Adapters-XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html#Type%20Adapters:%20XmlJavaTypeAdapter.)

(Most classes should be modified to avoid making fields public, but as it is, it is brief and working.)

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root{ // Training
    @XmlElement
    private A a;  // Brochure
    public Root(){}
    public A getA(){ return a; }
    public void setA( A value ){ a = value; }
}

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AFormatter.class)
public class A{  // Brochure
    private Collection<B> bees;
    public A(){
        bees = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public Collection<B> getBees() {
        if( bees == null ) bees = new ArrayList<>();
        return bees;
    }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class B{  // Course
    @XmlElement
    private String id;
    public B(){}
    public String getId(){ return id; }
    public void setId( String value ){ id = value; }
}

public class AFormatter extends XmlAdapter<BeeHive, A>{
    @Override
    public A unmarshal(BeeHive v) throws Exception {
        A a = new A();
        for( B b: v.beeList ){
            a.getBees().add( b );
        }
        return a;
    }
    @Override
    public BeeHive marshal(A v) throws Exception {
    BeeHive beeHive = new BeeHive();
        for( B b: v.getBees() ){
             if( b.getId().startsWith("a") ) beeHive.beeList.add( b ); 
        }                              
        return beeHive;
    }
}

public class BeeHive { // Courses
    @XmlElement(name="b")
    public List<B> beeList = new ArrayList<B>();
}
```

Alternatives: It would be quite simple if the regular getter of the B-list would return the ones that should be marshalled. If the application needs to see all, an alternative getter could be added. Or, the class could have a static flag that instructs the getter to return a List to be used for marshalling, or the regular list at other times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestions, but now the resulted xml is only:
    <A>
        <bees/>
    </A>

As in, none of the B instances are put in.

Comment: I had to backtrack a little and shake off the idea of adapting the Collection itself. See the completely rewritten answer.